# setOnMenuItemClickListener not working for Bottom App Bar when using app:actionLayout

Tags: android, android-menu, android-bottomappbar

I have used bottom app bar and the problem is when i used a custom layout for my menus using app:actionLayout in menu, the click is not working for these menus i.e setOnMenuItemClickListener for bottomappbar not working.?
It is working fine when actionLayout not used.

```
BottomAppBar bottomAppBar;
bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
bottomAppBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.announcement_menu);
bottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_all:
                        Log.d("Announcement", "All clicked");

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_rec:
                        Log.d("Announcement", "Received clicked");
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_sen:
                        Log.d("Announcement", "Sent clicked");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And the menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_all"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_menu_row_all"
        android:title="All"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_rec"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_menu_row_received"
        android:title="Received"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sen"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_menu_row_sent"
        android:title="Sent"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: maybe you need setclicklistener for each item like : R.id.action_all.setonclicklistener(this). try this!

Answer (score 0):

Got working with following:

```
View v = bottomAppBar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_rec).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Announcement", "Received clicked");
            }
        });
```